# How to do carousel page in xamarin android

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

I want to show a carousel page in my app. How can I do this? I used this link to create carousel page-https://github.com/sahilkhan99/learnings/tree/master/autoImageSlider

But I got some error in my code, is there any other links or solution to do this?

Please help me..

Comment: Please specify your question...

Comment: Do you want a simple viewpager (slider between pages) or an actual carousel, which slides back to start when you reach the end (more complex)?

Comment: Also, if you install android studio, you will be presented with a lot of finished typical examples, such as a viewpager :)... and it is fairly easy to rewrite into xamarin.

Comment: @MathiasKirkegaard I want actual carousel with page indicators

Comment: What's the error you got?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How to do carousel page in xamarin android

You could try to use [`InfiniteCycleViewPager`](https://github.com/martijn00/InfiniteCycleViewPagerXamarin).It's available in Nuget.It can be installed by
`Install-Package Xam.Plugins.Android.InfiniteCycleViewPager -Version 1.0.2`
This is a [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xlHQv2150wU) on YouTube.
Here is the code:

The MainActivity

```
[Activity(Label = "android", MainLauncher = true, Theme = "@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar")]
public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
{
    List<int> listImage = new List<int>();
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);            
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
        InitData();
        HorizontalInfiniteCycleViewPager viewPager = FindViewById<HorizontalInfiniteCycleViewPager>(Resource.Id.hicvp);
        MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(listImage, BaseContext);
        viewPager.Adapter = adapter;
    }

    private void InitData()
    {
        listImage.Add(Resource.Drawable.sample_1);
        listImage.Add(Resource.Drawable.sample_2);
        listImage.Add(Resource.Drawable.sample_3);
        listImage.Add(Resource.Drawable.sample_4);
        listImage.Add(Resource.Drawable.sample_5);
        listImage.Add(Resource.Drawable.sample_6);
        listImage.Add(Resource.Drawable.sample_7);
    }
}
```

The Main.axml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <com.gigamole.infinitecycleviewpager.HorizontalInfiniteCycleViewPager
        android:id="@+id/hicvp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:icvp_center_page_scale_offset="30dp"
        app:icvp_min_page_scale_offset="5dp"
        app:icvp_scroll_duration="1000"
        app:icvp_max_page_scale="0.8"
        app:icvp_min_page_scale="0.55"
        app:icvp_medium_scaled="false" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The item.axml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"></ImageView>
</LinearLayout>
```

The MyAdapter.cs

```
public class MyAdapter : PagerAdapter
{
    List<int> ListImages;
    Context context;
    LayoutInflater LayoutInflater;

    public MyAdapter(List<int> ListImages, Context context)
    {
        this.ListImages = ListImages;
        this.context = context;
        LayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.From(context);
    }

    public override Java.Lang.Object InstantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position)
    {
        View view = LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.Item,container,false);
        ImageView imageView = view.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.imageview);
        imageView.SetImageResource(ListImages[position]);
        container.AddView(view);
        return view;

    }

    public override int Count => ListImages.Count;

    public override bool IsViewFromObject(View view, Java.Lang.Object objectValue)
    {
        return view.Equals(objectValue);
    }
    public override void DestroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Java.Lang.Object objectValue)
    {
        container.RemoveView((View)objectValue);
    }
}
```